# Get-ADUser can't find all users

Tags: excel, powershell, active-directory

I'm reading in a list of users from a Excel spreadsheet one row at a time. Once I get that I'm attempting to get the user object in Active Directory that matches the username I pulled from the Excel file. Unfortunately, it gets the first user but then every user after that it says that it can't find them. Here's what I'm doing:

```
do
{    
    # Get the user's login name
    $userPrincipalName = $objWorksheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 1).Value()

    # Get the user description
    $description = $objWorksheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 2).Value()

    $intRow++

    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName -eq '$userPrincipalName'" -Properties Description

    if ($user)
    {
        if (!($user.Description))
        {
            $user | Set-ADUser -Description $description
            Write-Host "User" $userPrincipalName "was altered."

            $num_of_users_altered++
        }

        else
        {
            Write-Host "User" $userPrincipalName "already has a description."
        }
    }

    else
    {
        Write-Host "User" $userPrincipalName "was not found."
        $num_of_users_not_altered++
    }


} 
while ($objWorksheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 1).Value() -ne $null)
```

Now the first user (the one that is found) is in a different OU from the others. I've tried removing that user from the spreadsheet to see if the issue with them being in different OU's but it just didn't find any of them. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Is there whitespace in your excel sheet? Your logic looks like it works fine

Comment: No, not one bit of whitespace. I've even recreating the spreadsheet multiple times to make sure there was nothing wrong with the spreadsheet.

Comment: Off the top of my head i feel like your data could be the only issue. You loop structure appears to be working from what you said.

Comment: Right. I mean it's going through the loop and its telling me all the username and its saying that they were not found. So the loop itself should be working right. I just wasn't sure if I was doing anything wrong with the actual Get-ADUser command, because it seems to only work for that one user.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking for UPN and not SamAccountName? Not sure if we will make much headway but we could chat this out

Answer (score 0):

Your loop looks like it should work.

- **Are you sure that you have UPNs (`user1@mydomain.com`) for all users, and not samAccountName (`user1`)?**
- Do you get any results if you manually run `Get-ADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName -eq '$userPrincipalName'" -Properties Description` (replace `$userPrincipalName` with one of the values you get in a "not found"-message?
- What happends if you use this (`$userPrincipalName = $objWorksheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 1).Value().Trim()`)?
- Does it make a difference if convert your file to CSV? Personally, I would always recommend using a CSV-file with PowerShell. CSV-files are alot easier to work with.

sample:

```
Import-CSV -Path "c:\mycsvfile.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    #Modify to match your column names
    $upn = $_.userPrincipalName.Trim()
    $desc = $_.description.Trim()

    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName -eq '$upn'" -Properties Description

    if ($user)
    {
        if (!($user.Description))
        {
            $user | Set-ADUser -Description $desc
            Write-Host "User" $upn "was altered."

            $num_of_users_altered++
        }

        else
        {
            Write-Host "User" $upn "already has a description."
        }
    }

    else
    {
        Write-Host "User" $upn "was not found."
        $num_of_users_not_altered++
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, when I removed the comments before pasting the code I accidentally removed the $intRow++. Try looking at the code again.

Comment: I had tried to communicate some of these with the OP. Good use `.Trim()` code just to ensure there is no space.

Comment: @FrodeF. I didn't even think about what I was searching for being samAccountName instead of upn. As soon as I changed that and it started finding the users. Just got to figure out why it says I have insufficient rights to change this one user in the list.